# Disabling individual sites on a Craft 3 multisite

Tags: craft3, multi-site

Is there a way to disable non-primary sites on a multisite setup so that users are redirected to a 503 template?

I can't see any configurations that allow me to to this. All sites are either disabled or live.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this is something you'd do from your .htaccess file or public index.php files for each of the non-primary sites you define.

For example if you have a `public_html/index.php` for your English primary site and a `public_html/de/index.php` for your German site, your German one would just `header("Location: http://mysite.com/503");` to redirect.

Comment: That might work for some cases, but I think it's not a user-friendly way to disable a site.

For example, I am working on a website that has various countries sites in a different language, and I want to create extra countries and add data to these countries. But I do not want these to be available in the frontend yet. Wouldn't be simpler if I could have a lightswitch
  that would disable it?

Comment: Did you find a way bzin? Agree, it needs a simple way to disable for non-logged in users, but logged in admins can see it, whilst its in development. The only way I can think of is in the layout file at the top, check if user is an admin, and if they are not redirect to a 404. If they are, they will see the site as normal.